# Crystal is not generating code for upgraded report with UFL Library for upgraded project from VS2008 to VS2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

i have a solution developed in VS 2008 and 3.5 in VB with almost 38 projects (class libraries) in it. This whole thing is big project with almost 140 reports (crystal reports) in it.

now i install Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Crystal Report (CRforVS_13_0_7)
and upgraded my solution to .net 4.5 everything works fine.

some of my reports uses a library written in VB.net CRUFL for InWord support in indian rupee format

now i am facing problem with upgrading reports to new crystal report format.
when i open any report file and verify and save it asks me to save in new crystal report format if i choose yes to upgrade i get error from crystal code generator

```
Custom tool error: "Code generator 'ReportCodeGenerator' failed.  Exception stack = CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: UFL 'u212com.dll' that implements this function is missing.
Error in File repAbstract {B0F50159-6708-4E3E-A668-899D0616325C}.rpt:
Error in formula  drInWord: 
'UniSuiteReportingEXReportingEXToWords (ABS(Sum ({@drAmount})))'
UFL 'u212com.dll' that implements this function is missing.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportClassWriter..ctor(String filePath)
   at CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportClassWriter..ctor(String filePath, String resourceNamespace)
   at CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator.GenerateCode(String inputFileName, String inputFileContent)"  Z:\World Of Programming\Product\VS .Net\Products\Uni Suite\Uni Suite 2.0\Uni_Suite.Reports\repAbstract.rpt  1   1   Uni_Suite.Reports
```

- What I figured out that the problem is with CRUFL function,
- If I comment function in formula and just return normal string in it
  and flow the process report upgrades and works fine.
- If I add new report and use this function is formula that also works
  fine.
- I created completely new library written in 4.5 for any upgrading
  wizard errors but the behavior is same.

This is clear I cannot create all these reports again in new version, count is huge and some of them are very complex.

Am I missing something of is there anything I have to study first before upgrading my project

Please suggest

one more thing OS is windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: found this but http://www.crystalkeen.com/mm5/graphics/flyers/HowToInstallAndUseUFL.pdf but my system location is (C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86) it didn't worked

Comment: Is there a barcode generated from that formula, or is there a barcode at all in this report? And do you have the u212com.dll on your system?

Comment: no its not a barcode it writes amount in indian rupee format, its nothing to do with this dll same thing worked in new reports

Comment: Are you compiling your solution as "AnyCPU" by chance?

Comment: i already searched this and rebuild it with 32 setting but the result is same

Comment: In your Project Properties, what is your Target Framework?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40660/discussion-between-jack-gajanan-and-campagnolo-1)

Comment: I'm sorry but the chat is not working. Try this http://scn.sap.com/message/10238321 and this http://scn.sap.com/message/14104348 post for more information unless you already read them.

Comment: ufl lib is written by me, and smae thing is working in new report

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I've got. Hopefully somebody else will have an answer!

Comment: thanks i am also searching for the reason

Comment: guyis please any guesses

Comment: i have posted this to http://scn.sap.com/thread/3452634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a temporary solution for it. This seems to be a bug in crystal designer in visual studio on windows 8.1

Temporary solution is:

- Right click on report file and select properties
- Remove “CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator” from
  Custom Tool.
- Now report designer will not raise any error for any changes or
  testing, do updates or changes and save report.
- Close designer of report
- Now open properties and past
  “CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator” in custom
  tool and press enter. This will generate code for report without any
  error and report will also work fine

This will generate code for report without any error and report will also work fine
This definitely a bug in crystal report for visual studio I don’t know how to submit this bug to SAP but I will search and submit this to crystal report to help them improve this. Meanwhile this is a solution worked for me.

you can find communication regarding this here http://scn.sap.com/thread/3452634

**EDIT**

but now new issue after using above method report is not accepting any select filter and showing all data from database with select statement.

working on it... any help please

**EDIT**

Found solution for this also amazing, this is happening only with reports with UFL in same viewer OK

found solution here http://scn.sap.com/message/8179989#8179989

what you have to do is to remove following two lines from from designer where your viewer control is.

```
crystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = ""
crystalReportViewer.ViewTimeSelectionFormula = ""
```

**EDIT**

now i updated my crystal report to service pack 8 (v. 13.0.8.1216)

Link http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

But no luck still using method mentioned above

**EDIT**

i updated to crystal report service pack 10 (v.13.0.10.1385) & VS 2013 (64Bit windows 8.1 update 1)

but still no luck, using above method

Comment: Hi Jack, how to install UFL. can you tell me briefly

Comment: Dim _CRUFL As String = "C:\CRUFL_test.dll"

Comment: Dim Tcls As System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish = New System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish()

Comment: Tcls.GacInstall(_CRUFL)

Comment: Tcls.RegisterAssembly(_CRUFL)

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error code in C# VS2010.  I got it when adding Parameter fields to SubReports.  It seems to happen before I link a field to the Parameter from the Main report.  Just setting the links after creating the parameter seems to make the error go away again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I got this error and my fix was different...

Basically the error is responding to an out of date EF formula. I got the following answer through Viewpoint support.. 
OLD func. syntax throwing error: EFCityStateZip ({APPB.City},{APPB.State}, {APPB.Zip})

New func. syntax that works: ({APPB.City}&', '&{APPB.State}&' '& {APPB.Zip})